# XGBoost iterative training: Not having all 0,...,C labels in minibatch without erroring

Tags: xgboost, decision-tree, boosting

When training XGBoost iteratively for data too large to fit in memory, one may want to use "batches". The problem is, however, that each batch may not contain all `0,...,C` labels. This leads to the error `ValueError: The label must consist of integer labels of form 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class-1] -`

Is there a way to train XGBoost where we just have some subset of the labels, which may not contain zero?

The code has structure similar to this:

```
train = module.trainloader
test = module.valloader

# Train on one minibatch to get started 
sample = next(iter(loader))
X = xgb.DMatrix(sample[0].numpy(), label=sample[1].numpy())

params = {
    'learning_rate': 0.007,
    'updater':'refresh',
    'process_type': 'update',
}

# Get initial model training 
model = xgb.train(params, dtrain=X)

for i, (trainsample, valsample) in enumerate(zip(train, test)):
    X_train, y_train = trainsample
    X_test, y_test = valsample
    
    X_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, labels=y_train)
    
    X_test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test)

    model = xgb.train(params, dtrain=X_train, xgb_model=model)

    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    print(accuracy)
```